# Один UserControl для всех классов или несколько UserControl для каждого класса?

Tags: c#, winforms

В моей программе имеется множество `UserControl`'ов .Они похожи, но в тоже время отличаются. К примеру, они имеют одну и ту же форму, один тип заголовка, пары `textBox/label`, а отличаются текстом заголовка, цветом самого `UserControl`'а, количеством пар `textBox/label` и типом данных, которые могут содержать эти `textBox`'ы. `UserControl`'ы могут выглядеть таким образом:

[image]

[image]

и пр.

Я подумываю создать множество классов для каждого шаблона для содержания логики и данных. И только один класс типа `UserControl` для отображения.
Например:

- `Template` - Родительский класс.

  - `Template1` - Наследный класс. Содержит поля и логику первого шаблона.
  - `Template2` - Наследный класс. Содержит поля и логику второго шаблона.
  - `Template3` - Наследный класс. Содержит поля и логику третьего шаблона.
  - etc.
- `UserControlTemplate` - класс для отображения. Только один.

И я планирую создавать объект класса UserControlTemplate внутри определенного шаблона и просто передавать необходимые параметры контролу. Хорошая ли это идея? Или лучше создать отдельные `UserControlTemplate` классы для каждого шаблона? Например вот так:

- `UserControlTemplate` - Родительский класс.

  - `UserControlTemplate1` - наследный класс. Отображает только первый шаблон.
  - `UserControlTemplate2` - наследный класс. Отображает только второй шаблон.
  - `UserControlTemplate3` - наследный класс. Отображает только первый второй третий шаблон.
  - и пр.

Как думаете, какой вариант будет лучше?

Comment: Я думаю, что будет лучше первый вариант.

Comment: @Igor Спасибо за ответ! Тогда все данные, размер контрола, цвет, количество пар textBox/label и пр. лучше тоже передавать как параметры через конструктор UserControlTemplate?

Comment: Я бы создал класс, контейнер данных, создавал объект этого типа, заполнял его данными и передавал его в конструктор.

Comment: @Igor То есть в моем случае создать класс контаинер, в каждом шаблоне этот класс заполнять а потом передавать его в конструктор UserControlTemplate?